# Firebase: Check through cloud functions if user email is verified

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to check if email is verified through cloud functions 
i.e. if I have a uid for the user, can I check if the email is verified for that particular user. In my use case, I need to make sure that email is verified before transaction is executed. I want to check it server side

Sample cloud function:

```
exports.executeTransaction = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{ 

const userid = context.auth.uid 

//Check if email is verified
//I want to use context variable to somehow extract whether email is verified. Is there a way to do it ?
//Execute Transaction if email is verified
})
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs, context includes `decodedIdToken`, which already contains an `email_verified` field.

Thus all you need to do is this:

```
exports.executeTransaction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const { token } = context.auth;
  if (!token.firebase.email_verified)
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-precondition",
      "The function must be called while authenticated."
    );

  // ...do stuff
})
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https#.CallableContext

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken#email_verified

Comment: context.auth.firebase simply does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Never Mind, I managed to figure it out.

See following for anyone with similar issue:

```
exports.executeTransaction = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{ 
const userid = context.auth.uid 
//Check if email is verified
return admin.auth().getUser(context.auth.uid).then(user => {
//Check if email verified
  if(user.emailVerified)
  {
return "Verified"
}
else{
console.log("User Email not verified")
return "Not Verified"
}
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log(err)
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('Error Validating', err.message, err)
})
})
```